# How to find the subdocument via subdocument id in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find the subdocument in mongoose by subdocument id.

i am doing :

`mainDoc.subDocFieldName.id(sudocId);`

But it shows

```
'cannot find property id of undefined'
```

seems like `mainDoc.subDocFieldName` is `undefined`.

so how do i access the sub document.?

Comment: Show us the schema, show us some example code where you try to access the sub document.

Comment: Is this using the mongoose populate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by :

```
mainDoc[subDocFieldName].id(sudocId);
```

Actually I was using subDocument array.

Comment: please elaborate a bit more... am facing the same issue... neither the question nor answer is well defined