# unable to find subdocument using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wanted to find the subdocument with id and return the subdocument, not the parent document, my schema are as follows :

```
var coursesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 coursename:{type:String}
});

var parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 courses:[coursesSchema]
});

var Parent= mongoose.model('parent', parentSchema );
module.exports = Parent;
```

```
let data = Parent.courses.id(_id);
```

as given in the docs I tried to find the subdocument using .id, it is throwing error saying Cannot read property 'id' of undefined,

and after searching a lot found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586391/how-to-find-the-subdocument-via-subdocument-id-in-mongoose) I tried the same, apparently it also returned the same error.

```
let data = Parent['courses'].id(_id);
```

please help me with this, I am not able to get my head around with it

Comment: Try doing `const query = {
 courses: {
  $elemMatch: {
   _id
  }
 }
};
parents.find(query, (err, docs) => {

});` See this [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I have tried this, what is does is that it returns the whole parent document if it gets _id match in the courses subdocument, But what I was looking for is to directly find and return the subdocument itself -you see once we get the parent back from the DB we again have to filter it at the api level which results in more computation and even network payload sent from the hosted DB.

Comment: [try this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DoUAVWdnlrg)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, could you help me with [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vu6vDREuPb1) is what I am stuck with, I just need to get only one content document with matching key value. Btw, that example was really helpful.

Comment: [Try something like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vs2zPDwg41V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this using Aggregation operations as @KunalMukherjee pointed out in the comments [Here is a quick example to do so](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vs2zPDwg41V)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the subdocument, you have to do the following:

1. Look for the document
2. Reference the subdocument property

In your case, you have defined a Model. Based on this model, you would need to:

```
Parent.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("abcd12345678901234567890") }, function(err, doc) {
  let subDocument = doc.courses;
  ...
}
```

The reason you get the "undefined" error is because the `courses` subdocument doesn't have a field called `id`. It only has a field called `coursename`.

Comment: this would return the parent document with its given id, what I needed was to find the subdocument by its id and return the subdocument itself.

Comment: and forgot to add it to previous comment that courses is an array of subdocuments not just an array of objects so it does have a  _id  field on it.

Comment: Coming across this much later, but dealing with the same issue. Mongoose's docs say you can access the _id by the id() method: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html. This works for me if I find the parent doc first by its id and then use parent.subarray.id() in the promise, but is not working for me if I do the find by the subdoc _id: parent.find({"subdoc._id": subdocId}). Finds the parent but the subdoc array is undefined...